# $f : \mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ is differentiable at $c$ if and only if $f(c+h)-f(c) = o(\langle v, h\rangle)$ for some $v$ : constant vector

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

This question is from Introduction to Mathematical analysis, Steven A. Douglass Exercise 8.3 (d).

Let $f$ be a real-valued function defined on an open set $U$ in $\mathbb R^n$. Let $c$ be a point of $U$. Show that $f$ is differentiable at $c$ in $U$ if and only if $f(c+h) - f(c) = o(\langle v ,h\rangle)$ for some constant vector $v$ in $R^n$.
(The vector $h$ is the variable.)
($\langle v,h\rangle$ denotes the inner product of $v$ and $h$.)

I tried to solve the question, but I couldn't prove both direction, and here's what I tried.

$f$ is differentiable at c $\Rightarrow$ for every $\varepsilon > 0,\  \exists \delta>0,\  |f(c+h)-f(c)- \langle \nabla f(c) , h\rangle| \le \varepsilon|h|$.

Since I know that there exists some vector $v$ $s.t$
for every $\varepsilon > 0$, $\exists \delta>0,\ |f(c+h)-f(c)- \langle v , h\rangle| \le \varepsilon|h|$ $\Rightarrow$ $f$ is differentiable at $c$,
I wanted to show the problem's condition for vector $v$ and the equation above are equivalent, but I think it doesn't work.

From the differentiablity, I know that $|f(c+h)-f(c)|$ $\le$ $|\langle \nabla f, h\rangle|+ \varepsilon |h|$ as |h| goes to $0$. Of course, dividing by $|\langle \nabla f, h\rangle|$ does not satisfy the condition of the problem. Even if we divide the both side by $|\langle v , h\rangle|$ for general vector $v$, the term $\varepsilon \frac{|h|}{\langle v,h\rangle}$ is being arbitrarily large if vector $v$ is perpendicular to $h$, so I even doubt if the 
theorem of the problem is true.
Any ideas for the question?

Comment: What does *differentiable* mean in this context?  Frechet differentiable?

Comment: I think it is.(I never heard about the term and I'm not sure, so will write the definition from the textbook) Definition : $f$ is differentiable at $c$ : there exists a function $F(c;t)$ : $R^n\ \rightarrow R$ which is linear, and for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists a deleted neighborhood $N'(0)$  $s.t$ $t \in N'(0) \Rightarrow |f(c+t) - f(c) - F(c;t)| < \epsilon||t||$

Comment: Thanks.  That is one way to say Frechet differentiable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The theorem you're asked to prove is wrong. By Cauchy-Schwarz, it implies $f(c+h)-f(c)=o(\|h\|)$, which is obviously wrong. For example, with $n=1$, $$\exp(h)-1=h+o(h)\neq o(h)$$

Comment: @JeongminPark If you're satisfied with this answer, upvote it and press the check mark.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't have enough reputation for upvoting, I pressed check mark, thank you.